# cannot build Caliburn Micro tutorial code. No definition for 'AssemblySource.Select'

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to get started with Caliburn Micro following the tutorial at http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/2/1/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/

However, the code in the tutorial produces errors. On that page, the following Bootstraper code is provided:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives;

public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<AppViewModel>
{
  private CompositionContainer container;

  protected override void Configure()
  {
    container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

    CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

    batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
    batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
    batch.AddExportedValue(container);

    container.Compose(batch);
  }

  protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
  {
    string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
    var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

    if (exports.Count() > 0)
    {
      return exports.First();
    }

    throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
  }
}
```

I can find no class (generic or otherwise) called `Bootstrapper`, but I've been able to extend `BootstrapperBase` instead.

However, I am running into trouble on the line where `container` is declared.  AssemblySource does not have a method named `Select`.

So what gives?  Is this a difference between version 2.0 and 1.0?  If so, are there some updated learning materials I can follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been some breaking changes between 1.5.2 and 2.0.0. Most of which are outlined in the [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/migrating-to-2.0.0). Although it appears the change to Bootstrapper is missing. That should be fixed soon.

Instead of inheriting `Bootstrapper<T>` you should inherit `Bootstrapper` and add a method like

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>();
}
```

to your Bootstrapper.

The missing method Select is because `AssemblySource.Instance` is an `IObservableCollection` and the `Select` method is the LINQ extension method. Adding a using for `System.Linq` will correct that error.

Comment: I believe you meant to inherit from BootstrapperBase and not Bootstrapper.

Comment: Also, i could not get my app runnig antil I added :
public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }